# How to get the full name of a remote bluetooth device in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm a fresh man in Android programming. I am facing a problem that I can just get a partial name of an Android remote device with API `BluetoothDevice.getName()` and `intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME)`, but I need the full name.  Please tell me the different between the two API, most important, how can I get the full name?